# How to install file in include directory yocto

Tags: yocto

I'm trying install files extracted from tar file, but non of my files are installing under usr/include directory on target board, but I see my files under temp/work/aarch64/recipedir/image/usr/include/mydir/ and include/myfile.h. While building I haven't got any errors.

```
do_install() {
     
     install -d ${D}${includedir}
     mkdir   -p ${D}${includedir}/mydir
     install -m 0644 ${S}/include/myfile.h ${D}${includedir}
     install -m 0644 ${S}/include/mydir/*.h ${D}${includedir}/mydir/
}
FILES_${PN} += "${includedir}/mydir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in `${includedir}` is put into `${PN}-dev` by default.

c.f.: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n316

You have to remember that a file can only be in one package. To determine in which package a file is going to make it, it's pretty simple. Starting from leftmost package in `PACKAGES`, the first package to have the file matching any path in `FILES_<pkg>` will have the file.

By default, `${PN}-dev` appears before `${PN}` in `PACKAGES`.

c.f.: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n294

You can check which package has your file without "reverse-engineering" the whole thing by running `oe-pkgdata-util find-path '/usr/include/mydir'`.

If you really want this header file in your system (why?), you can either add `${PN}-dev` to your image or hack things (remove the -dev package from `PACKAGES` or move `${PN}` before `${PN}-dev`, if you only have one file in `${includedir}`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have ran `oe-pkgdata-util find-path '/usr/include/mydir'` by replacing with actual directory name, but I got an error as `ERROR: Unable to find any package producing path /usr/include/mydir`. Actually I had downloaded a tar package which contains .so and .h files, which are need to be compiled with my application, so I had installed .so file in libdir successfully, but not .h files. Anyway I don't need .h files at runtime, but I'm not sure how bitbake provides path during compilation. So, I thought to install header files in include directory.

Comment: I've always used `oe-pkgdata-util find-path` with a glob for files or a complete path so maybe it works better this way (basically add `/*` at the end of your path). You need to not have cleaned your `${TMPDIR}` between a build and executing `oe-pkgdata-util` though.

Comment: To share files between recipes for compilation purposes, any file installed in any directory part of `SYSROOT_DIRS` (there's already sane defaults, e.g. `${includedir}` is in it) will be available for other recipes given they have added your original recipe to `DEPENDS`. The parts of the sources of your recipe will be available in recipe-sysroot directory in the `${WORKDIR}` directory of other recipes. The sysroot is passed to recipes' build-system via Yocto variables so reuse them as much as possible.
c.f.: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-SYSROOT_DIRS

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, I have to install .h files into the `${includedir}` to be part of `SYSROOT_DIRS` so that when this recipe name is added to `DEPENDS` in other recipe it can share all files.

Comment: s/all files/all files installed in `SYSROOT_DIRS`/ but yes :)

Comment: Thank you! Now my .h files are in `usr/include` directory on target board. I have one more question, does `temp/work/aarch64/recipedir/image/usr/include` is also considered as `SYSROOT_DIRS`? So that, there will be no necessary to install .h files on target board.

Comment: `temp/work/aarch64/recipedir/image` is `${D}` of your recipe. It's from there that files are being split into packages and also made available to other recipes through `SYSROOT_DIRS`. c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-D
You can triple-check by adding your recipe to `DEPENDS` of another recipe, and check into `temp/work/aarch64/anotherrecipedir/recipe-sysroot` if your header files are there. If they are here but "another recipe" failed to build, check that the source code is using Yocto variables which define the sysroot (e.g. `CC` for C software).

Comment: Sorry for asking again, I'm new to Yocto. How to link my recipe to package config? `PKG_SEARCH_MODULE` cannot find installed package.

Comment: That's a question a bit too far from the original question to my taste, please create a new post.

Comment: I have created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785595/how-to-add-built-recipe-to-package-config-in-yocto