# How to add built recipe to package config in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I had installed .so and .h files into the build by extracting from a tar file, when compiling my application with installed package I got an error as `PKG_SEARCH_MODULE` cannot find installed package. So, how do I add my installed recipe to package config?

Comment: I don't know much about package config but maybe the `pkgconfig` bbclass would be of interest to you? https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#pkgconfig-bbclass

Comment: @qschulz I'm interested, seems to be solution, but I don't have .pc file in tar file. May be following error can give more information. `| -- Checking for one of the modules 'libmylib'
| CMake Error at recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:711 (message):
|   None of the required 'libmylib' found
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   CMakeLists.txt:14 (PKG_SEARCH_MODULE)`